# Get the rows ONLY where the time difference between the current and the following row is under 5 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

TSQL Query
[Accounts with Different Times of transaction done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4UJg.png)

I need help in figuring out a way to pull only the records where the `txn_time` difference between the current and next row is under 5 minutes.
The `txn_time` is sorted.

Looking at the attached image, only rows 1,2,3,6,7,8 should be shown, since the time difference between each of these row is under 5 minutes.

Any ideas would be helpful.

### Sample Data:

```
rowno   txn_Date_Time   txn_time    accountNo
1   2017-10-31  11:50:47.0000000    98989898
2   2017-10-31  11:52:23.0000000    98989898
3   2017-10-31  11:52:23.0000000    98989898
4   2017-10-31  11:59:03.0000000    98989898
5   2017-10-31  12:05:13.0000000    98989898
6   2017-10-31  12:41:06.0000000    98989898
7   2017-10-31  12:42:44.0000000    98989898
8   2017-10-31  12:44:02.0000000    98989898
9   2017-10-31  15:23:19.0000000    98989898
10  2017-10-31  16:19:17.0000000    98989898
```

Comment: Please put the sample data in text inside the question, it will increase your chances of getting a quality answer. I do have a few questions, by the criteria you mentioned of under a 5 minute difference shouldn't row 3 be excluded? (11:52:23 to 11:59:03 > 5 min). What about if the time crosses days? (10/31/17 23:59:06 to 11/1/17 00:01:47 would be under 5 min) Also posting any attempts you have made so far would help others help you too.

Comment: Hi @tarheel. The date will always be for one day so only have to check under 5 minutes within a day.  your question for row no. 3 has actually time of 11:52:23 which is compared to row no. 2 which also has time of 11:52:23. so this should be in the result. similar goes for row no. 8.   12:44:02(row 8) - 12:42:44(row 7) is under 5 minutes. hence should be shown on the result. appreciate your assistance. so result should show rows 1,2,3,6,7,8 since there time difference between these rows is under 5 minutes. row 6 and 8 shouldn't be left out.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on those. I notice that the entire sample data set is for a single `accountNo` value, will there ever be more than one to consider? If so, should the records pertaining to each `accountNo` value be evaluated separately or as one large group?

Comment: @tarheel yes there will be more than one account no to consider and it should be evaluated in a large group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+ it is much more efficient to use `LEAD` and `LAG` functions instead of self-join.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        rowno
        ,txn_Date_Time
        ,txn_time
        ,accountNo
        ,LEAD(txn_time) OVER (PARTITION BY accountNo ORDER BY txn_time, rowno) AS next_time
        ,LAG(txn_time) OVER (PARTITION BY accountNo ORDER BY txn_time, rowno) AS prev_time
    FROM T
)
SELECT
    rowno
    ,txn_Date_Time
    ,txn_time
    ,accountNo
FROM CTE
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(second, prev_time, txn_time) < 5 * 60
    OR
    DATEDIFF(second, txn_time, next_time) < 5 * 60
ORDER BY txn_time, rowno;
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot Vladimir. this is awesome. love your answer. Finally managed to get the desired result using your method.

Comment: hi Vladimir, what if we had more than one accountNo. how would we link it to only get the difference in time under 5 minutes for the same accountNo's.   basically show all accountNo's rows whose difference is under 5 minutes.

Comment: @MoshinKhan, I think it is as simple as adding `PARTITION BY accountNo`. I updated the answer.

Comment: the partition bit worked absolutely fine and did the difference calculation for each unique accountno as expected. thanks for the simple ideas. I wasn't well versed with LEAD() LAG() and partition by, but this query explains a lot with real time data. thanks a lot.

Comment: nice solution, I learned about it from your answer and used it today for something my boss asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using SQL 2012 you can use [Window Offset Functions](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/microsoft-sql-server-2012-how-write-t-sql-window-functions-part-2) such as LAG and LEAD. @vladimir beat me to it, however; he and I put together similar solutions.

To keep things interesting I'll demonstrate how to optimize your query so that neither LAG nor LEAD cause SQL server to require a sort to satisfy your query. The type of index I'm creating is referred to as a ***POC index*** which is discussed [here](http://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-how-write-t-sql-window-functions-part-3).

For simplicity I'm using a single column datetime data type for txn_date_time. I'll create two identical tables and run my solution against them. The second table will have a poc index on it.

**Sample data**

```
-- sample data
if object_id('tempdb..#table')  is not null drop table #table;
if object_id('tempdb..#table2') is not null drop table #table2;
go
create table #table
(
  rowno int identity,
  txn_date_time datetime,
  accountNo int
);
create table #table2
(
  rowno int identity,
  txn_date_time datetime,
  accountNo int
);

-- populate #table 
declare @dt varchar(9) = '20171031 ', @acn int = 98989898;
insert #table (txn_date_time, accountNo)
values
(@dt+'11:50:47',@acn), (@dt+'11:52:23', @acn), (@dt+'11:52:23',@acn),
(@dt+'11:59:03',@acn), (@dt+'12:05:13', @acn), (@dt+'12:41:06',@acn),
(@dt+'12:42:44',@acn), (@dt+'12:44:02', @acn), (@dt+'15:23:19',@acn),(@dt+'16:19:17',@acn);
-- populate #table2    
insert #table2 (txn_date_time, accountNo)
select txn_date_time, accountNo from #table;

-- create unique clustered index on #table2
create unique clustered index uq_cl_table2 on #table2(txn_date_time, rowno);
GO
```

Run the same query against both tables keeping in mind that the second table has the poc index on it.

```
-- #table
select rowno, txn_date_time, accountNo
from
(
  select rowno, txn_date_time, accountNo, 
    nextDt = datediff(minute, txn_date_time, lead(txn_date_time, 1) over (order by txn_date_time)),
    prevDt = datediff(minute, lag(txn_date_time, 1)  over (order by txn_date_time), txn_date_time)
  from #table
) fixedDates
where nextDt <= 5 or prevDt <= 5;
-- #table2
select rowno, txn_date_time, accountNo
from
(
  select rowno, txn_date_time, accountNo, 
    nextDt = datediff(minute, txn_date_time, lead(txn_date_time, 1) over (order by txn_date_time)),
    prevDt = datediff(minute, lag(txn_date_time, 1)  over (order by txn_date_time), txn_date_time)
  from #table2
) fixedDates
where nextDt <= 5 or prevDt <= 5;
```

Note the execution plans. Adding the poc index removed the sort and made the query four times more efficient.

[image]

Comment: thanks @Alan Burstein, I will try this out too and advise. this method seems more efficient in terms of timing.

Answer (score 1):

Try a self join to attach the previous row, then union a second query that self joins to the previous row:

```
SELECT
     t1.rowno
    ,t1.txn_Date_time
    ,t1.txn_time
    ,t1.accountNo
FROM [table] t1
JOIN [table] t2
    ON t2.rowno = t1.rowno + 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.txn_time, t2.txn_time) < 5

UNION

SELECT
     t1.rowno
    ,t1.txn_Date_time
    ,t1.txn_time
    ,t1.accountNo
FROM [table] t1
JOIN [table] t2
    ON t2.rowno = t1.rowno - 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t2.txn_time, t1.txn_time) < 5
```

Comment: thanks for this self join. it works but it leaves out/drops the last row/preceding row from where the difference is over 5mins. the expected result was to have rows: 1,2,3,6,7,8  but it only showed rows 1,2,6,7.        Rows 3 and 8 were dropped.

Comment: Leaving efficiency aside, this query relies on `rowno` being consecutive, without gaps. OP didn't state that in the question.

Comment: this query worked too. also gets the desired result. thanks supergrady

Comment: this query helped me in the situation where we had multiple account no's. so I amended the join to also have "and t2.accountNo=t1.accountNo".  this will find the difference only for the same accountno's